# Revealing module ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oop

I have this code:

```
my.data = function () {

var getAuth = function (userName, password) {
        var model = JSON.stringify({ "UserName": userName, "Password": password });
        var result;

        $.ajax({
            url: my.baseUrl + "api/AD",
            type: "POST",
            data: model,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                result = data;
                return result;
            }
        });        
    }

    return {      
        getAuth: getAuth
    }
}();
```

when I call getAuth , i can see data returns "true" but the the calling function - 
var result = my.data.getAuth(username,password); returns undefined.
any idea?

Comment: @undefine: He set async: false

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it will return `undefined`, the returned value is of the success function. Not the value of the `getAuth` function. You should change to:

```
my.data = function () {

var getAuth = function (userName, password) {
        var model = JSON.stringify({ "UserName": userName, "Password": password });
        var result;

        $.ajax({
            url: my.baseUrl + "api/AD",
            type: "POST",
            data: model,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                result = data;
            }
        });      
        return result;
    }

    return {      
        getAuth: getAuth
    }
}();
```

Even though this solution works, the use of `async: false` is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons:
1. When you switch ajax to `async: false`, you shouldn't pass `success: function(){...}` property to options hash. Instead of this you should to use chain.
2. When you use `return` in `success` function you return from `success` function only, not from `getAuth`.
Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: my.baseUrl + "api/AD",
  type: "POST",
  data: model,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  async: false,
}).success: function (data) {
  result = data;
};
return result;
```

And couple of notes. As you know switching to `async: false` can cause long delay. This is bad practice and it is deprecated in last JQuery versions. Instead of this you should to use callbacks. Third argument of your `getAuth` method can be a function, that you should run when query is success:

```
var getAuth = function( userName, password, callback ){
  $.ajax({
    url: my.baseUrl + "api/AD",
    type: "POST",
    data: {userName: userName, password: password},
    success: function (data) {
      callback( data );
    }
  });        
}
```

And use this like here:

```
my.data.getAuth( 'someusername', 'somepassword', function( data ){
  alert( 'It looks like your authorized successfully' );
});
```